# How to delete a site-column reference from a content-type in Sharepoint Client model

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I am trying to delete a site-columns from the sharepoint website directly from my code. These site-columns are currently referenced under some content-types. So when I execute a code

```
//Delete the site-column
conFields.DeleteObject();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
break;
```

it throws an exception

> Site columns which are included in content types cannot be deleted. Remove all references to this site column prior to deleting it.

Can anyone please suggest a way to first remove that reference from the content-type and then delete the site-column.

Here's the code:

```
//availableCT is my content-type
 FieldCollection fieldColl = availableCT.Fields;
clientContext.Load(fieldColl);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
foreach (Field field in fieldColl)
{
  //columnFromList is the column taht is to be deleted
  if (field.InternalName.Equals(columnFromList))
  {
    field.DeleteObject();
    clientContext.executeQuery();
  }
}
```

Whenever I'm running this code, it throws me an exception:

> Additional information: Site columns which are included in content types or on lists cannot be deleted. Please remove all instances of this site column prior to deleting it.

Please suggest me a way to achieve this task programmatically. FYI, when I try to delete it from my Sharepoint website, it gets deleted without any error.

Comment: Can anyone please help me find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since the site column is referenced in content type the specified error occurs.

The following examples (implemented as [Extension methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)) demonstrate how to delete site columns when it is referenced in content type(s):

```
public static class FieldExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Remove column and reference from specific content types
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="field"></param>
    /// <param name="contentTypeId"></param>
    public static void DeleteObject(this Field field,string contentTypeId)
    {
        var ctx = field.Context as ClientContext;
        if (!field.IsPropertyAvailable("Id"))
        {
            ctx.Load(field, f => f.Id);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        //Firstly, remove site column from content type
        var contentType = ctx.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById(contentTypeId);
        var fieldLinks = contentType.FieldLinks;
        var fieldLinkToRemove = fieldLinks.GetById(field.Id);
        fieldLinkToRemove.DeleteObject();
        contentType.Update(true); //push changes
        //Then remove column
        field.DeleteObject();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Remove column and references from all content types
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="field"></param>
    /// <param name="includeContentTypes"></param>
    public static void DeleteObject(this Field field, bool includeContentTypes)
    {
        var ctx = field.Context as ClientContext;
        if (!field.IsPropertyAvailable("Id"))
        {
            ctx.Load(field, f => f.Id);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        //Firstly, remove site column link from all content types
        ctx.Load(ctx.Site.RootWeb.AvailableContentTypes, cts => cts.Include(ct => ct.FieldLinks));
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (var ct in ctx.Site.RootWeb.AvailableContentTypes)
        {
            var containsField = ct.FieldLinks.Any(fl => fl.Id == field.Id);
            if (containsField)
            {
                var fieldLinkToRemove = ct.FieldLinks.GetById(field.Id);
                fieldLinkToRemove.DeleteObject();
                ct.Update(true); //push changes         
            }
        }
        //Then remove site column
        field.DeleteObject();
    }
}
```

**Usage**

Delete site column and references from *all* content types:

```
using (var ctx = ClientContext(webUri))
{        
    var siteFields = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Fields;
    var fieldToDel = siteFields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
    fieldToDel.DeleteObject(true);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Delete site column and reference from content type:

```
using (var ctx = ClientContext(webUri))
{        
   //find content type
   var result = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Site.RootWeb.AvailableContentTypes.Where(ct => ct.Name == "Order Document"));
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();

   if (result.Any())
   {
       var ctId = result.First().Id.StringValue;
       var siteFields = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Fields;
       var fieldToDel = siteFields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
       fieldToDel.DeleteObject(ctId);
       ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   }
}
```